# Developing ASP.NET WEB API service application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I will be developing my first ASP.NET WEB Api service application but I am not so sure how to start.
If I were to have 20 tables on my database, do I have to create 20 Api Controllers?

For testing purposes I have been creating one api controller for each table.  I do not know if it is the best approach but it works. I will be using Unit of Work pattern and Dependency Injection (Unity for webapi).
Does anybody have any thought or recommendation ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are the tables?   are you planning to just have the API do basic restful CRUD on them [get,post,delete]?   i think that might help to know what you want to do.

Comment: yes, that is reason for using WebApi (Restful).  I am planning to develop this service system so that other application can connect an consume data thru this service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your services should not be a reflection of how you store your data. In fact, many would consider this to be an anti-pattern or bad practice.

There are 2 popular trends/patterns for designing an API service layer nowadays (and many others that I won't mention here)

## [Service Oriented (SOA)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/#service_oriented_model)

This would lead you towards grouping your services by business domain/function or something similar. It would also be task/action oriented. so each service contain actions and tasks that the system should perform.

#### Example

Such as if I were developing an e-commerece system, I would be creating these services:

- Security (*for Users, Groups, signup, login, lost password, etc.*)
- Catalog (*Products, Stock Levels, Reviews, etc.*)
- Orders (*New orders, order status, cancellation, etc.*)
- Fulfillment (*Shipping, updating stock, etc.*)

### [Resource Oriented (RESTful)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/#resource_oriented_model)

In this architecture you will be designing your services as if they provide access to groups of resources (but not explicitly an activity, action, command, etc.)

HTTP protocol is used as a communications layer, so each resource has its URI/N and a HTTP operation is performed to control this resource (**GET** *for queries*, **POST** *for inserting*, **PUT** *for update*, **DELETE**, etc.)

#### Example

Using the same e-commerce case above, this is how it might look in a RESTful service architecture:

- Users (all CRUD operations)
- Products (all CRUD operations)
- Product Reviews (all CRUD operations)
- Orders (all CRUD operations)

> For more detailed examples of a RESTful API could be found at [SpreeCommerce](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/summary.html) and [Shopify](https://docs.shopify.com/api/introduction/getting-started) and how they structured their API endpoints.

This architecture is recently gaining popularity and has wide acceptance, mainly because it allows the back-end to support multiple client applications to be built upon (think Web, and Mobile) but beware that it will force you to shift most of the system development/coding towards the client side (HTML/JS in case of a web app/site)

I would also encourage you to read more about [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), and other design and architecture patterns. although I don't recommend specific materials for reading.

#### Things to consider when writing an API

> - Document your API well. use an intuitive tool, something like [Apiary](https://apiary.io/) and their underlying technology [API Blueprint](https://apiblueprint.org/)
> - Use an automated testing tool for your API. Best if it can read the use cases from your API documentation and generate unit tests based on them (that is possible using API Blueprint technology, Shameless Plug: [API Blueprint host for asp.net](https://github.com/BishoyDemian/api-blueprint-aspnet-host) can help simulate an API using it's documentation)

Comment: Thanks for this quick response to my question.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response to my question.  The RESTful scenario is pretty much what I am trying to achieve.  Each Api Controller has a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE operations.  This is where I am feeling confused.  In your second example, each of them has its own API controller.  If I were to have Product and ProductType (two tables) then do I have to have two API controllers one for each of them?  Or One single Api controller will be able to perform the RESTful operations.  I think that if you respond to this last question, everything will be clear for me.   Thank you.

Comment: @aaquino4u that is a valid question, but unfortunately the answer is "it depends". It depends mainly on the usage scenario of such Resources/Entities, if the client of your API will need to modify those resources directly then yes, they should have their own Resource URI with their operations. I also doubt that *all* Entites should be Resources in a RESTful API.

Comment: thanks a lot for your replies and you are absolutely right.  When developing this application, I should have in mind on who is/are going to consume this service and what actions they will be performing.  Thank you for your expertised advice.

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to have 20 tables on my database, do I have to create 20 Api Controllers

No. You just need a controller for the functionality it needs. It doesn't matter how or where it's stored. When you have a controller that provides methods related to placing orders it will generally interact with a lot of tables (customer, inventory, product, invoice, order, order lines, shipping, etc.).

Comment: In MVC I was able to Add, Update, Delete data to many tables but I am not sure if that is a good practice, uhmm.. no is not.  In Web API things are different.  I wonder was is the best approach to my question.